# Why is my OAuth2 authorization redirects with malformed angular routing URL query string?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, box, oauth-2.0

I am using Box API service in my app with OAuth2 authorization.

I am passing my redirect URL to Box Authorization page as 'http://localhost:3000/#/index/oauth'

But after granting permission, here is the URL that I am redirected to:
http://localhost:3000/?state=get_token&code=vi2ql2qtg0i0IHhaBWHBGLd6zG61Yg0v#/index/oauth.

Does it have something to do with angular routing that I am using?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Authrorization Code grant from OAuth2 which returns an authorization code that needs to be sent back to the server. The server then exchanges that code along with client id and client secret for an access_token.
Since anything after the # in the url is not sent to the server the code and the state has to stay before #.

I think the redirect url you have specified in Box API, has angular routing with # fragment in it. So the box api is persisting it, but after the query string parameters. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: Is there a way to add the query string parameters at the end of the URL?

Comment: The redirection url you have used while setting up your client has to be an absolute URI. As per the OAuth2 spec, fragment components are not allowed.